# List not update on RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

After loading a refresh widget, the list of values that should be displayed on the widgets on the screen is not updated. What is causing this? With hot reload, it updates, but when forcing the value manually, it doesn't update with the dropdown.

**Flutter Code:**

```
  RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                setState(() async {
                    lista= await getList(context);
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: lista.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return getRow(lista[index]);
                          })),
                ),
```

Answer (score -1):

change the on refresh part like below

```
onRefresh: () async {
          var listItems = await getList(context);
          setState(() {
            lista = listItems ;
          });
```

Comment: your solution not update list display value

Comment: are you getting any error?? Change this part of code and then try restarting the app.